# Late Binding to dll based on CPU architecture

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, late-binding

I am currently writing a helper library that connects to shop floor PLCs via [Software Toolbox's TopServer](http://www.toolboxopc.com/).

The TopServer library has separate versions for x86 and x64 architectures and I want to load the appropriate version at runtime using late binding based on the CPU architecture of the calling code. The methods in the two libraries have the same signatures.

I can use reflection to load the relevant object using the below code but I am wondering what is the best method of using this instance in the calling code.

```
public class LateBinding
{
    public static T GetInstance<T>(string dllPath, string fullyQualifiedClassName) where T : class
    {
        Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
        Type t = assembly.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName);

        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
}
```

As I'm late binding I don't get the types pre-runtime so was thinking that creating an interface based on the libraries method signatures would be a good way to implement both version.

Does anyone have a view on this method or recommendations on other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target DLLs only vary by the target architecture and the assemblies are *not* strongly named, an interface is not necessary.

My suggestion is to name them *_64.dll and *_86.dll respectively and pick one to compile against.

At runtime, all you need to do is `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile` the correct file.

Comment: The problem with compiling to a specific version is that that compiled dll will not work on the other architecture. If I compile to x86 the Software Toolbox dll will not run on a x64 architecture

Comment: Are you compiling **your** assemblies as 'Any CPU', 'x86' or 'x64'?

Comment: Any Cpu would be the ideal.

Comment: @PhilMurray When you build, you are always going to have to target one of the assemblies. Is 64bit even required? I always compile everything to x86 if I have unmanaged/architecture specific code. Keeps things simple. You can do this by changing your entry assembly to x86.

Comment: Understand that sentiment but this assembly has other dependencies which would need to be changed to x86. Changing all the dependencies is not something I want to do.

Comment: @PhilMurray If the dependencies are .net assemblies, you can leave them as 'Any CPU' and they will load just fine - as long as the _entry_ assembly is x86.

Comment: That's the problem, this will be part of a library where I would prefer not to target x86 specifically.